# PHP while loop problem, is not creating a new row

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image]i try to get some data from a database and put it in a table.
the problem is the loop, the second row is not going to the new row, is continuing in same row. I checked the code and I can not see the problem.
Infact in the database i have 3 row and in the website is geting just 2 of them and booth in same row.
Can anybody help me?

```
    <h1>view database</h1>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Shop list</h1>
        </div>
    
    <?php
    
    
    $query = "SELECT shop_name, shop_phone_number, shop_email, shop_address_no, shop_address_street, shop_town, shop_county, shop_postcode, shop_address_country FROM shop";
    
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    
    $num = $stmt->rowCount();
    
    //button to add new shop
    
    echo "<a href='index.php?page=shop' class='btn btn-primary m-b-1em'>Add new shop</a>";
    if($num>0){
      echo "<table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>";
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Phone</th>";
        echo "<th>Email</th>";
        echo "<th>Address no/name</th>";
        echo "<th>Street</th>";
        echo "<th>Town</th>";
        echo "<th>County</th>";
        echo "<th>Post Code</th>";
        echo "<th>Country</th>";
        echo "<th>Action</th>";
      echo "</tr>";
    
      while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row);
    
        echo "<tr>";
    
          echo "<td>{$shop_name}</td>";
          echo "<td>{$shop_phone_number}</td>";
          echo "<td>{$shop_email}</td>";
          echo "<td>{$shop_address_no}</td>";
          echo "<td>{$shop_address_street}</td>";
          echo "<td>{$shop_town}</td>";
          echo "<td>{$shop_county}</td>";
          echo "<td>{$shop_postcode}</td>";
          echo "<td>{$shop_address_country}</td>";
          echo "<td>";
    
            echo "<a href='read_one.php?name={$shop_name}' class='btn btn-info m-r-1em'>Read</a>";
    
            echo "<a href='read_one.php?name={$shop_name}' class='btn btn-primary m-r-1em' >Edit</a>";
    
            echo "<a href='#' onclick='delete_user({$shop_name})' class='btn btn-danger>Delete</a>";
            
          echo "</td>";
    
        echo "</tr>"; 
      }
      echo "</table>";
    }
    else{
      echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>No Records found.</div>";
    }
    ?>
    </div>
?>
```

Comment: What does the generated html look like in your browser? Any clues there? Incidentally, your links to read/edit/delete would be better done using the shop ID rather than the name - what if you get two shops with the same name?

Comment: A hint my brother game me when I learned PHP: Your code looks like php echoing HTML. Try to make it look like HTML and weave in php when necessary.

Instead of: echo "<td>{variable}</td>"
Try: <td>{{variable}}</td>

This will help you a lot to distinguish between what is code and what is html.

Comment: You should close your attributes, e.g. `class='btn btn-danger>Delete</a>"`